# IDE Exception when trying to create a new controller in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I created an "Area" for a bit of functionality in my MVC3 project and then changed my mind. I didn't see a way to remove the "Areas" from my project, So I just deleted the "Areas" folder. Now when I try to create a new controller, I get this exception message in VS2010 Ultimate:

> Exception calling "GetControllerScaffolders" with"1" argument(s): "The
>   WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called after the pipeline
>   has been closed. Please contact Microsoft Support Services"

Related facts:

- I know that I used this method to add a controller before on this project.
- I haven't added a controller in at least a month.
- I just created a new MVC3 project and tried to add a controller and got the same exception
- No new extensions were installed recently.
- No updates to VS2010 or the MVC framework recently.

I'm not sure if deleting the "Areas" folder caused this issue (actually, it seems less likely, after the same thing happens in a brand new project), but it was the last thing I did before trying to add the controller that resulted in this exception.

Anybody have this problem? Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: I'm assuming you've already done this but it sounds like you may need to create a new project and add your code to it or roll back to when you had the area if you have it in source control.